# Create large amount of user accounts in OS X Lion Server's Server App/Server Admin/Workgroup Manager

Tags: macos, osx-lion

I'm trying to managing iOS devices by OS X Lion Server on Mac Mini.

Now I need to create more than 100 user accounts in Server App. If there's any way to do this without creating each account one by one? Writing script?

http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/UserMgmt_v10.6.pdf
According to this document, the exported file of accounts is a XML file. But I find no where to create or edit this file in a efficient way.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Open Directory (which you probably should with that amount of users) one option is to use `dscl` which is probably a little easier to automate. There's a [thread at Apple Discussions](https://discussions.apple.com/message/9448669#9448669) describing how to add users to a group.

Answer (score 1):

Workgroup Manager (part of the [Server Admin Tools package](http://support.apple.com/downloads/#server%20admin%20tools)) can import tab-delimited text files with a little work.  When you do the import, you'll need to tell it the file's format -- what the record and field delimiters are (generally newline and tab), then what data each field contains.  See [this video](http://vimeo.com/15050876) for an example of the process.

If you need to set attributes that aren't in the file, you can either select all of the imported accounts and set the attribute for all of them at once (the video shows doing this for the home directory location), or (if you think of it before doing the import) create a template account with the relevant settings, save it as a preset (there's a pop-up menu at the bottom of WGM's window), then select that preset in the import dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Passenger http://macinmind.com/?area=app&app=passenger&pg=info

If you have more than 20 users you might want to buy it for $60 or do what I do and group them by 20 users and run it 5 times.